# remove elements with corresponding zeros in another matrix matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have two matrices A & B in Matlab, for example

```
A=[0,0,1,2,3,0,4,2,0]
B=[2,3,1,2,2,3,4,4,1]
```

What I want to do is to set elements in B to zero where they have the same position as zero elements in A. So in my example:

```
A=[0,0,1,2,3,0,4,2,0]
B=[2,3,1,2,2,3,4,4,1]
```

I want B to be like this:

```
B=[0,0,1,2,2,0,4,4,0]
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it using [logical indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/) like so: `B(A==0) = 0`

**EDIT:**

You can also do it like this: `B.*(A~=0)` which will be easier to generalise to higher dimensions using `bsxfun` as per your comment below.

Comment: thanks Dan! it works, I have another question, If B is a multidimenstional matrix so that A is 3x3 and B is (3x3)x3, how to do the same thing for every 3x3 matrix in B? I know that this may be trivial but I'm just new in doing this. Many tHanks

Comment: `bsxfun(@times, A ~= 0, B)`

Comment: the problem is that A is uint16 and B is uint8 so its giving an error how to overcome this?

Comment: You should ask this as a new question. What is the error? You could probably just cast B to also be uint16: `bsxfun(@times, A~=0, uint16(B))`, but this is a strange error

Comment: this is the error appearing "Error using ==> times
Integers can only be combined with integers of the same class, or scalar doubles."

Comment: the problem with casting B to double is that its an uint8 image, so when i write M=bsxfun(@times, A~=0, double(B)) the next line which is     set(h2,'CData',M); gives an error "Error using ==> set
TrueColor CData contains element out of range 0.0 <= value <= 1.0"

Comment: So then cast back to `uint8` afterwards??

Answer (score 1):

The only problem with doing something that Dan suggests is if A and B are not the same size. You can still however do this with a little bit of extra work.

```
indices = find(A==0);
indices = indices(indices <= length(B));
B(indices) = 0;
```